# How to get the PSID after user clicked the SEND-TO-MESSENGER button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

This is my code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: "xxx",
    xfbml: true,
    version: "v2.6"
  });

  FB.Event.subscribe('send_to_messenger', function(response) {
   // callback for events triggered by the plugin
     console.log('inside the send_to_messenger'); 
     if ( response.event == 'clicked' ) {

     };


  });

};

(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

So now, how do I get the PSID of the user ?

Comment: You don't get it in client-side code at all - you get it when your webhook receives the message they sent.

Comment: @CBroe Is there not a way to get it via SEND TO MESSENGER button ? I need a way to get the PSID before users start send messages to the page. I saw that manychat and chatfuel do that. How can I do ? Thanks :)

Comment: And what makes you think they did that client-side? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messaging_optins

Answer (score 2):

You need to subscribe to the `messaging_optins` webhook event. When the send to messenger button is clicked, you should get the PSID in `sender.id` prop of the event.